# Draw moving dot based on accelerometer

Tags: bbc-microbit

How do I draw a single dot that moves left and right based on accelerometer x/y input?

When I am using the plot method I noticed that pixels get turned on but stay on.

How do I draw a single moving dot?

Here's my current attempt:

[image: code example, multiple lights turned on]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `forever` loop add a `clear screen` block. This will clear all the dots before drawing any more.

[image: micro:bit menu pick for clear screen]